# triggering hover through div

Tags: html, css

I want to make a specific kind of background for my website that's comprised of 9 columns that have an animation which changes their background color, and a pause on hover for the animation.

is it possible to keep the hover effect happening when i'll hover divs abover the one in the background?

also, are css3 animations difficult to display for clients? what if i want to have more than this background, like a few animations running on an svg, should i start "saving up" memory already?

thanks for the help

see example jsfiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/gxzhry0x/

```
html --

<div class="pillars-container">
    <div class="pillar" id="pillar1"></div>
    ...
    <div class="pillar" id="pillar9"></div>
</div>


css --

.pillars-container {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:-9000;
}

.pillars-container * {
    display:inline-block;

}

.pillar {
    opacity:0.8;
    margin:0 -4px -2px 0;
    padding:0;
    width:11vw;
    height:100vh;

    animation-name: pillars;
    animation-duration: 170s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.pillar:hover {

    opacity:0.7;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

.pillar#pillar9{
    width:12vw;
}

@keyframes pillars { 
    0%      {background-color:#8F70FF;}
    2.5%    {background-color:#63C7E8;}
... etc }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the property `pointer-events: none`, which allows all mouse-events to pass through an element.

The issue with `pointer-events: none` however, is that the element that you'd like the events to happen "through" needs an absolute position. While it's a bit of a work-around, see if perhaps this could be a solution for you:

```css
body {
}

h1 {
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 90%;
}

.pillars-container {
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
    z-index: 0;
}

.pillars-container * {
 display:inline-block;

}

.pillar {
 opacity:0.8;
 margin:0 -4px -2px 0;
 padding:0;
 width:11vw;
 height:100vh;

 animation-name: pillars;
 animation-duration: 170s;
 animation-timing-function: linear;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.pillar:hover {

 opacity:0.7;
 animation-play-state: paused;
}

.pillar#pillar9{
 width:12vw;
}

@keyframes pillars { 
 0%   {background-color:#8F70FF;}
 2.5%  {background-color:#63C7E8;}
 5%   {background-color:#78FF96;}
 7.5%  {background-color:#E8E759;}
 10%  {background-color:#FFC360;}
 12.5%  {background-color:#E8C26A;}
 15%  {background-color:#E3FF8A;}
 17.5%  {background-color:#74E8A5;}
 20%  {background-color:#75C2FF;}
 22.5%  {background-color:#53E85B;}
 25%  {background-color:#E8A149;}
 27.5%  {background-color:#FFF567;}
 30%  {background-color:#E8BD42;}
 32.5%  {background-color:#C0FF5F;}
 35%  {background-color:#4CE8A3;}
 37.5%  {background-color:#4A9AFF;}
 40%  {background-color:#9875FF;}
 42.5%  {background-color:#74C9E8;}
 45%  {background-color:#8BFFA7;}
 47.5%  {background-color:#E6E86A;}
 50%  {background-color:#FFCB72;}
 52.5%  {background-color:#FFDE5B;}
 55%  {background-color:#91E855;}
 57.5%  {background-color:#74FFD7;}
 60%  {background-color:#5F87E8;}
 62.5%  {background-color:#CF5FFF;}
 65%  {background-color:#FF4DEA;}
 67.5%  {background-color:#584FE8;}
 70%  {background-color:#62F2FF;}
 72.5%  {background-color:#45E84C;}
 75%  {background-color:#FFF34A;}
 77.5%  {background-color:#6FFF49;}
 80%  {background-color:#44E8D3;}
 82.5%  {background-color:#6178FF;}
 85%  {background-color:#D24EE8;}
 87.5%  {background-color:#FF6A4C;}
 90%  {background-color:#FFAA35;}
 92.5%  {background-color:#E84139;}
 95%  {background-color:#B94BFF;}
 97.5%  {background-color:#3076E8;}
 100%  {background-color:#32FFB1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes pillars {
 0%   {background-color:#8F70FF;}
 2.5%  {background-color:#63C7E8;}
 5%   {background-color:#78FF96;}
 7.5%  {background-color:#E8E759;}
 10%  {background-color:#FFC360;}
 12.5%  {background-color:#E8C26A;}
 15%  {background-color:#E3FF8A;}
 17.5%  {background-color:#74E8A5;}
 20%  {background-color:#75C2FF;}
 22.5%  {background-color:#53E85B;}
 25%  {background-color:#E8A149;}
 27.5%  {background-color:#FFF567;}
 30%  {background-color:#E8BD42;}
 32.5%  {background-color:#C0FF5F;}
 35%  {background-color:#4CE8A3;}
 37.5%  {background-color:#4A9AFF;}
 40%  {background-color:#9875FF;}
 42.5%  {background-color:#74C9E8;}
 45%  {background-color:#8BFFA7;}
 47.5%  {background-color:#E6E86A;}
 50%  {background-color:#FFCB72;}
 52.5%  {background-color:#FFDE5B;}
 55%  {background-color:#91E855;}
 57.5%  {background-color:#74FFD7;}
 60%  {background-color:#5F87E8;}
 62.5%  {background-color:#CF5FFF;}
 65%  {background-color:#FF4DEA;}
 67.5%  {background-color:#584FE8;}
 70%  {background-color:#62F2FF;}
 72.5%  {background-color:#45E84C;}
 75%  {background-color:#FFF34A;}
 77.5%  {background-color:#6FFF49;}
 80%  {background-color:#44E8D3;}
 82.5%  {background-color:#6178FF;}
 85%  {background-color:#D24EE8;}
 87.5%  {background-color:#FF6A4C;}
 90%  {background-color:#FFAA35;}
 92.5%  {background-color:#E84139;}
 95%  {background-color:#B94BFF;}
 97.5%  {background-color:#3076E8;}
 100%  {background-color:#32FFB1;}
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="pillars-container">
  <div class="pillar" id="pillar1"></div>
  <div class="pillar" id="pillar2"></div>
  <div class="pillar" id="pillar3"></div>
  <div class="pillar" id="pillar4"></div>
  <div class="pillar" id="pillar5"></div>
  <div class="pillar" id="pillar6"></div>
  <div class="pillar" id="pillar7"></div>
  <div class="pillar" id="pillar8"></div>
  <div class="pillar" id="pillar9"></div>
 </div>
 <div>
  <h1 class="title" style="background-color: white;">hello ervyone</h1>
 </div>


</body>
```

Comment: thank you this is perfect !
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to keep the hover effect happening when i'll hover divs abover the one in the background?

Yes, if div is located outside of pillars.

Snippet below:

```css
h1 {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.pillars-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -9000;
}

.pillars-container * {
  display: inline-block;
}

.pillar {
  opacity: 0.8;
  margin: 0 -4px -2px 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 11vw;
  height: 100vh;
  animation-name: pillars;
  animation-duration: 170s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.pillar:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.above {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.above:hover {
  background: lightgray;
}

.pillar#pillar9 {
  width: 12vw;
}

@keyframes pillars {
  0% {
    background-color: #8F70FF;
  }
  2.5% {
    background-color: #63C7E8;
  }
  5% {
    background-color: #78FF96;
  }
  7.5% {
    background-color: #E8E759;
  }
  10% {
    background-color: #FFC360;
  }
  12.5% {
    background-color: #E8C26A;
  }
  15% {
    background-color: #E3FF8A;
  }
  17.5% {
    background-color: #74E8A5;
  }
  20% {
    background-color: #75C2FF;
  }
  22.5% {
    background-color: #53E85B;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: #E8A149;
  }
  27.5% {
    background-color: #FFF567;
  }
  30% {
    background-color: #E8BD42;
  }
  32.5% {
    background-color: #C0FF5F;
  }
  35% {
    background-color: #4CE8A3;
  }
  37.5% {
    background-color: #4A9AFF;
  }
  40% {
    background-color: #9875FF;
  }
  42.5% {
    background-color: #74C9E8;
  }
  45% {
    background-color: #8BFFA7;
  }
  47.5% {
    background-color: #E6E86A;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #FFCB72;
  }
  52.5% {
    background-color: #FFDE5B;
  }
  55% {
    background-color: #91E855;
  }
  57.5% {
    background-color: #74FFD7;
  }
  60% {
    background-color: #5F87E8;
  }
  62.5% {
    background-color: #CF5FFF;
  }
  65% {
    background-color: #FF4DEA;
  }
  67.5% {
    background-color: #584FE8;
  }
  70% {
    background-color: #62F2FF;
  }
  72.5% {
    background-color: #45E84C;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: #FFF34A;
  }
  77.5% {
    background-color: #6FFF49;
  }
  80% {
    background-color: #44E8D3;
  }
  82.5% {
    background-color: #6178FF;
  }
  85% {
    background-color: #D24EE8;
  }
  87.5% {
    background-color: #FF6A4C;
  }
  90% {
    background-color: #FFAA35;
  }
  92.5% {
    background-color: #E84139;
  }
  95% {
    background-color: #B94BFF;
  }
  97.5% {
    background-color: #3076E8;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #32FFB1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes pillars {
  0% {
    background-color: #8F70FF;
  }
  2.5% {
    background-color: #63C7E8;
  }
  5% {
    background-color: #78FF96;
  }
  7.5% {
    background-color: #E8E759;
  }
  10% {
    background-color: #FFC360;
  }
  12.5% {
    background-color: #E8C26A;
  }
  15% {
    background-color: #E3FF8A;
  }
  17.5% {
    background-color: #74E8A5;
  }
  20% {
    background-color: #75C2FF;
  }
  22.5% {
    background-color: #53E85B;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: #E8A149;
  }
  27.5% {
    background-color: #FFF567;
  }
  30% {
    background-color: #E8BD42;
  }
  32.5% {
    background-color: #C0FF5F;
  }
  35% {
    background-color: #4CE8A3;
  }
  37.5% {
    background-color: #4A9AFF;
  }
  40% {
    background-color: #9875FF;
  }
  42.5% {
    background-color: #74C9E8;
  }
  45% {
    background-color: #8BFFA7;
  }
  47.5% {
    background-color: #E6E86A;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #FFCB72;
  }
  52.5% {
    background-color: #FFDE5B;
  }
  55% {
    background-color: #91E855;
  }
  57.5% {
    background-color: #74FFD7;
  }
  60% {
    background-color: #5F87E8;
  }
  62.5% {
    background-color: #CF5FFF;
  }
  65% {
    background-color: #FF4DEA;
  }
  67.5% {
    background-color: #584FE8;
  }
  70% {
    background-color: #62F2FF;
  }
  72.5% {
    background-color: #45E84C;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: #FFF34A;
  }
  77.5% {
    background-color: #6FFF49;
  }
  80% {
    background-color: #44E8D3;
  }
  82.5% {
    background-color: #6178FF;
  }
  85% {
    background-color: #D24EE8;
  }
  87.5% {
    background-color: #FF6A4C;
  }
  90% {
    background-color: #FFAA35;
  }
  92.5% {
    background-color: #E84139;
  }
  95% {
    background-color: #B94BFF;
  }
  97.5% {
    background-color: #3076E8;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #32FFB1;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="pillars-container">
    <div class="pillar" id="pillar1"></div>
    <div class="pillar" id="pillar2"></div>
    <div class="pillar" id="pillar3"></div>
    <div class="pillar" id="pillar4"></div>
    <div class="pillar" id="pillar5"></div>
    <div class="pillar" id="pillar6"></div>
    <div class="pillar" id="pillar7"></div>
    <div class="pillar" id="pillar8"></div>
    <div class="pillar" id="pillar9"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1 class="title" style="background-color: white;">hello ervyone</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="above">div above</div>
</body>
```

> also, are css3 animations difficult to display for clients? what if i want to have more than this background, like a few animations running on an svg, should i start "saving up" memory already?

It really depends on the desired animation & project priorities, but yes some animations could turn to be memory & CPU hogs and may lag depending on the browser being used. Ideally you would test them in as many browsers as you can to ensure performance on all of them. The more effects you add, more resources are consumed the higher chance to suffer lag spikes.

You can also investigate the [transform property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) a bit, while limited to properties such as rotate, scale, move, skew, translate, perspective, it may be of interest that you could significantly cut-down the CPU usage since in most cases, takes advantage of GPU acceleration, lessening the burden on the CPU.

Comment: In regards to the first question, I believe OP wants to maintain the hover effect, but not have elements in front of the background "block" theevent from happening, as in my example. That being said, the second portion is informational. +1

Comment: Thanks Santi, I read back the post and while not 100% clear I think you are right, I'll vote yours as well. Regards.

Comment: Transform property contains everything i need for my project i hope i'll manage to make it as optimized as possible! thank you for the info i'll try other browsers!